# OpenVPN through NetworkManager fails, but not through console application

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have an openvpn server in my office and I want to connect to it with an Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

When I use the following command `openvpn --config my.ovpn` I can connect to my server and can easily ping devices that are located in my network. I get an IP from the IP subrange that my network is connected with 192.168.1.x, so all good.

Now where I fail is to make it work through NetworkManager.

I tried the following:

```
sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file /path/to/my.ovpn
```

Then I connect

```
sudo nmcli connection up my
```

And I get a success response

```
Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/27)
```

I check my connection and see that I don't get a right IP, I just get a 192.168.255.6 IP which is not correct.
ifconfig

I can ping 8.8.8.8 for example and surf the web when I am connected, but I can't ping any devices within my network.

I don't see an relevant error in /var/log/syslog.

What am I doing wrong and where can I start to debug this thing?